# use line buffering when piping output to file

Tags: perl, buffer

I have a perl program that prints to `stdout`, which I then pipe into a file, like this:

```
./skript.pl > file.txt 2>&1
```

This makes the output of that skript buffer. However, I would like to be able to see what the skript is working on at the moment, so I am trying to find a way to enable line buffering in this setup, so that output is printed as soon as a `\n` appears. (This is the normal behaviour if I just print to the terminal.)

I need a solution that is available without installing anything on CentOS.

Changing stuff inside the perlscript is an option. I already tried `$|`, but that is doing more than I want: it messes up the `cat file.txt` output if the end of the current line is not printed yet.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249723/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to run your script with [stdbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf), which has an option for line buffering:

```
stdbuf --output=L --error=L command
```

The advantage is that you don't have to modify the code. You can also use `stdbuf` with utilities which don't have the source code available, or when building such utilities is tricky.

Comment: Usually, stderr is already line buffered

Answer (score 6):

In your script you can use:

```
STDOUT->flush;
```

to flush the output buffer.

You can even set `STDOUT->autoflush(1);` globally.

To flush on newlines only try:

```
STDOUT->autoflush(0);
open STDOUT, ">/tmp/script.out"
.
.
close STDOUT;
```

Comment: Hm, autoflush does the same same as putting in `$|`, i.e. also flushing when lines are not complete, which breaks my ability to grep out error messages.

Comment: Create a handle to STDOUT which points to a file. If it exists it will be overwritten, hence the '>'. Perl will flush automatically when a newline is printed to a file handle.

Comment: This works also when using `>/dev/tty` for example so no, a regular file is not required.

Answer (score 1):

How about just redirecting via stderr? It should be unbuffered by default:

```
./skript.pl 2> file.txt 1>&2
```